# Move element by index in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
arr = [50, 30, "+"]
```

I would like to move "+" in between 50 and 30 through iteration.

I thought `each_with_index` would do the trick but so far no luck. This is a part of the process of making Reverse Polish Notation. (If anyone is interested, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

```
def evaluate(arr)
   arr.each_with_index {|ele, index| index-1 if x=="+"} 
end
```

I would like to move operator like `=`, `-` and `*` by one index so it will return `50 - 30`. Thanks!

Comment: Considering that this concerns RPN, does your question really have anything to do with `+`? Do you really just want to just swap the last two elements of `arr`, whatever they are? After all, it's only the top two elements of the stack that are ever swapped in RPN. (I am reminded of the language FORTH, which I thought was pretty cool.)

Answer (score 3):

```
arr.values_at(0, 2, 1)
#=> [50, "+", 30]

arr.values_at(0, 2, 1).join(" ")
#=> "50 + 30"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
arr[-1], arr[-2] = arr[-2], arr[-1]
```

This swaps the last two elements of the array.

Comment: This makes sense, as only the last two elements would be swapped with RPN.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary array:

```
def evaluate(arr)
   temp = arr.dup
   arr.each_with_index { |ele, index| temp[index-1] = ele }
   temp 
end
```

Another way is to repeat the array twice and grab the elements at indices 1-3:

```
(arr * 2)[1..3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but if you're looking to implement RPN in Ruby, you don't need to do any array munging. You can iterate your ops and maintain your value stack directly:

```
def rpn(*ops)
  stack = []
  ops.each do |op|
    case op
    when Numeric
      stack.push op
    else
      value = stack.pop
      receiver = stack.pop
      stack.push receiver.send(op, value)
    end
  end
  stack.first
end

puts rpn 5, 1, 2, "+", 4, "*", "+", 3, "-" # => 14
```

The fun thing is that since this is Ruby, operations are just messages you send to the receiver, so you can do things beyond basic math - for example, to get the greatest common denominator of two numbers, Ruby provides the "gcd" method, which you can feed into your RPN parser!

```
puts rpn 64, 24, "gcd" # => 8
```